# Pipenv install can't get the latest version of dependency (importlib-metadata-4.5.0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and struggling with dependency installation with `pipenv`,

During my `python3 -m pipenv install` , I got this

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement importlib-metadata==4.5.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-n8kyp_ul-requirements/pipenv-8ejg4ox3-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: No matching distribution found for importlib-metadata==4.5.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-n8kyp_ul-requirements/pipenv-8ejg4ox3-requirement.txt (line 1))
```

It looks like python cannot find the version `4.5.0` of `importlib-metada` , and Here are the version of my python and pip:

```
pip 21.1.2 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Been trying for several hours now, any help is really appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have ```importlib-metadata```? If yes, then try upgrading them?